# Signing .Net Code with Verisign

Tags: c#, verisign

I'm not sure why they can't simplify the process of signing code. It seems that every time a release comes out, it takes a day or more to figure out. We use Verisign and have a current pfx file.

I have an application that runs as administrator, so I need to sign both the application as well as the installer. I managed to accomplish this once several months ago, and release. This release, I decided to simplify the process, and set up Visual Studios to automatically sign the required files, using Properties -> Signing for each project. Then I ran my script while building the installer as a PostBuildEvent to sign that.

I thought everything was going good, as the installer gave the company name. However, when I ran the application, "Unknown" was displayed in the UAC. I decided to go back to the way I was doing it before, building, signing the files, building the installer, and finally signing it. This had worked three months ago, but now I am still getting the "Unknown" issue in the UAC popup.

I did not add any new classes to the solution, so my signing scripts should still be valid. I cannot figure out what I may be doing wrong. Is there any good documentation on how to sign with Verisign or simple rules that should be followed? It seems like calling `signtool.exe sign /f "Verisign.2012.pfx" /p myPassword "C:\...\Installer.msi"` on all .exe and .dll files after building, then creating the installer and calling the same on the .exe and .msi file should ensure that everything is signed and I shouldn't be seeing "Unknown."

Is there anyone out there with more experience than I (I am sure several) who may see the gaping hole in my understanding, and set me on the correct path? Thank you.

Comment: Side note: Can you please clarify who are "they" in "why they can't ..."? So far your question says "absolutely nothing changed in last several month but now build script fails" - there is likely some configuration/environment/script that you omitted from question...

Comment: There were changes to methods, but no new items were added. My notes show that I had a second script that called the signing script, but this is not on the signing system anymore. I cannot recall if it did anything other than call the signing script. Is there something more than needs to be done when signing?

Comment: Have you setup the assembly information. The process of signing code is not difficult, the process also has not changed, seems like this is user error.  We need more information about the scripts.  You don't seem to "remember" very much.

Comment: @Ramhound, I realize that this is caused by a user error. Unfortunately, I was not able to determine what that error might be, which was why I posted this question to the community. I have no training in signing, and the documentation that I have been able to find seems to be taking me in the wrong direction. If you happen to know of a good place that could walk me through the process, I would love the information.

Comment: @Tim: AFAIK -- and perhaps what I'm saying is valid only for ClickOnce applications -- it makes a difference whether you sign the *manifest*, or the *assemblies* (DLLs/EXEs) of your application. With ClickOnce, it's enough to sign the manifest to get rid of the "Unknown origin" warning. Signing the assemblies would not affect that warning at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined what I had been doing wrong. I was building the project and then signing it. After that, I was building the installer and signing that. However, with some testing I discovered that building the installer was stripping the digital signature from my files.

The correct way to sign with VeriSign on a VS project is not to create an installer that uses project output. Instead, manually select and add the files to your installer. After that, you will need to add a post-build event (properties -> Build Events -> Post-build event command line) that signs each projects output.

Thank you to those who suggested solutions.